# Determine which version of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to write to short code snippet in python, to determine which version of OpenCV has been installed in my System. How do i do it ?
Thank you.

Comment: Anything more to this? Do you have the Python bindings to OpenCV? Is this for Windows and/or Linux and/or Mac, etc? Are you assuming that OpenCV's libraries will be installed to some specific location, or will the location of binaries be passed in?

Comment: Hey, it is assumed that OpenCV is installed. But what if i had just cv installed. I think there is nothing called \_\_version\_\_ in cv

Comment: *I think* is not conclusive enough, how about checking it first?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> from cv2 import __version__
>>> __version__
'$Rev: 4557 $'
```

If that doesn't work then, use `cv` instead of `cv2`.

Comment: Hey, it is assumed that OpenCV is installed. But what if i had just cv installed. I think there is nothing called \_\_version\_\_ in cv.

Answer (score 4):

One line way can be like below:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Convenient functions to check OpenCV version in run-time

```
def cv2():
    return opencv_version("2")

def cv3():
    return opencv_version("3")

def cv4():
    return opencv_version("4")

def opencv_version(version):
    import cv2
    return cv2.__version__.startswith(version)
```

Useful when performing `cv2.findContours()` since return signature varies by version

```
# Using OpenCV 2.X or OpenCV 4
if cv2() or cv4():
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Using OpenCV 3
elif cv3():
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal write:

- for python 2.X `python2 -c 'import cv2; print cv2.__version__'`
- for python 3.X `python3 -c 'import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)'`