# Python opencv returns Bad Properties

Tags: python, c, opencv

I have the C code which works and returns good properties:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    CvCapture *capture = NULL; 
    const char* filename = "foo.mov";

    capture = cvCreateFileCapture(filename);
    int w = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int h = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    std::cout << "Width:  " << w << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Height: " << h << std::endl;
```

but the Python equivalent just returns 0 for everything:

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('foo.mov')

print capture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

This returns `0.0`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. check the open cv version in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248880/determine-which-version-of-opencv) and in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030640/how-to-determine-opencv-version) :

   > > > from cv2 import **version**
   > > >       **version**

   and using `CV_VERSION` macro.
2. what is the output for 
   `capture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)`
3. Are the python and foo.mov located on the same dir?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So the version for both are the same- 2.4.2.  The height property is 0.0 as well.  And the foo.mov is actually located in a different folder, I just put foo.mov there for brevity.